# How to set up the client to automatically shut down after a long time without using it

Tags: python-3.x, grpc-python

My stubs use a lot of methods, I can't recreate channels and close them every time I use them, and I can't put them all with because they are random. So I want the channels I created to close automatically when timed out.
I'm going to create channels for my root method, other channels that use root methods, and if this root method is no longer in use, I want to be able to automatically turn off the channel, or if this root method is not in use for a long time, it will automatically turn off the channel

```
@staticmethod
    def _create_client(workspace):
        workspace._client = TreeLabClient(token=workspace.token)


   def __init__(self, token: str):
        self.metadata = [('access_token', token)]
        if not os.getenv('ip'):
            os.environ['ip'] = get_env_ip()
        self.channel = grpc.insecure_channel(os.getenv('ip'))
        self.client = treelab_service.TreeLabApiServiceStub(self.channel)
        self.connectivity_state = _ChannelConnectivityState(self.channel)
        self.stub = treelab_service.TreeLabApiServiceStub(self.channel)
    def close(self):
        self.channel.close()
    @wait("WorkspaceCreated")
    def create_workspace(self, create_workspace_input: CreateWorkspaceInput):
        return self.stub.CreateWorkspace, create_workspace_input, self.metadata
    @wait("WorkspaceUpdated")
    def update_workspace(self, update_workspace_input: UpdateWorkspaceInput):
        return self.stub.UpdateWorkspace, update_workspace_input, self.metadata
    @wait("CoreCreated")
    def add_core(self, add_core_input):
        return self.stub.AddCore, add_core_input, self.metadata
    @wait("CoreRemoved")
    def remove_core(self, remove_core_input: RemoveCoreInput):
        return self.stub.RemoveCore, remove_core_input, self.metadata
    @wait("CoreUpdated")
    def update_core(self, update_core_input: UpdateCoreInput):
        return self.stub.UpdateCore, update_core_input, self.metadata
    @wait("TableCreated")
    def add_table(self, add_table_input: AddTableInput):
        return self.stub.AddTable, add_table_input, self.metadata
```

I want to be able to have the channel of the GRPC set the expiration time